# Open ssl ecncrypted string decryption using unix command

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I have encrypted a plain text using openssl_encrypt method in php. The code is given below.

```
 $plain_text = 'hello world';
 $password = '1224567892abcdef1231567390a1cde2';
 $iv = '3234367890fbceef';
 $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;

 $enc_data = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($plain_text, 'aes-256-ctr', $password, $options, $iv));

 echo $enc_data;
```

This php code generates this encrypted string: 3fd4e82b5c21ad4c2abd74

And for decrypting I am using this php code:

```
$plain_text = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($enc_data), 'aes-256-ctr', $password, $options, $iv);
```

But I want to decrypt this encrypted code using unix command in terminal. Could anyone help me on this?

I have tried with this command:

```
echo -n "3fd4e82b5c21ad4c2abd74" | xxd -r -p | openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -K 1224567892abcdef1231567390a1cde2 -iv 3234367890fbceef -d -nosalt
```

But I am not getting the expected plain text.

I am looking for some unix command using which I can get the decrypted plain text.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you talking about [UNIX](http://opengroup.org/unix) and not [Linux](https://www.kernel.org/)? If so, please specify one, or the other, as a tag underneath your question. That way specialists in the OS can more easily find your question.

Comment: In the OpenSSL statement key and IV must be hex encoded, see [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/EGp).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try and let you know

Comment: Thank you @Topaco. My issue has been solved.